# Cocos2d Action only being run once

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to run an animation on a sprite each time a button is pressed.

But for some reason, the action is only ran once and wont run again like i need it to.

Here is my action if it helps.My action is declared as an id instance variable.

```
    moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(60,self.position.y+200)];
```

Comment: Your sprite already move to (60,self.position.y+200) position on first click... How will work next clicks??

Comment: could you post more code, on your action instance creation and run ? Also, are you sure you're moving the correct sprite, and the button events are always caught ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to re-use the same action? Like so:

```
moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(60,self.position.y+200)];
[self runAction:moveUp];

// some time later …

[self runAction:moveUp];
```

Then this won't work. You have to create a new action every time, like so:

```
CCAction* moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(60,self.position.y+200)];
[self runAction:moveUp];

// some time later …

CCAction* moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(60,self.position.y+200)];
[self runAction:moveUp];
```